# Replacing reserved characters in filename

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement to download files from cloud to windows. while windows does not allow :?|'<>*!\" these characters in filename. I need to replace these characters and then convert back to these characters again in future. Hw do I do it in Java. Right now I am using regex

```
filename.replaceAll(INVALID_CHARACTER_REGEX, invalidCharReplacement);
```

But I do not want to replace with single character and also I need to onvert back to original filename in future. please help

Comment: I have a feeling that your question is very specific. If you try to generalize it, you might find the answer yourself. If you still think it's valid, please be more specific and clear with what you're trying to do

Comment: What do you want to replace them with, then? Something similar to a URL, where special characters (like `:`) are replaced by percent-encoded hex values (like `%3A`)?

Answer (score 1):

regex is not the right tool, regex can match invalid characters but not replace with other specific sequences. To be able to do the reverse operation a special escape character may be chosen, something like URLEncoder with `%` however with URLEncoder `*` remains the same.

Note that even if URLEncoder doesn't encode `*`, URLDecoder decodes `%2A`.

encoding function could be

```
URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8").replace("*","%2A");
```

and decoding function

```
URLEncoder.decode(string, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Instead of renaming the file. I just converted to filename to base64string and then convert back before uploading to cloud. That solves my problem. SOrry if my question wasnt specific